# Systematically remove files from specific branches, while keep tracking on others

Tags: git

My project use git in the following manner :

1. `master` => production
2. `staging` => staging
3. `feature/*` => feature branches

I have a some translation files (en_us.ids.json) with ids on them to allow quick editing from the browser. Those file are only relevant in feature branches, cause our QA changes the translations if needed on those branches, but those files should be ignore/delete on `master` and `staging`.

is there a simple way to remove each file names `(*.ids.json)` from my repository when merging to `staging` or `master` while keep the tracking of those file in branches that are `feature/*` ?

This should work on a pipelines, and not just on local, so editing `.git` folder would not really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in general.  Files, in Git, are *not stored in branches*.  Files are stored in *commits*.  A branch name is a way Git lets you find *one specific commit;* that one commit then lets you and Git find earlier commit(s).

To see why it's impossible, consider the following repository that has just one branch named `main`.  This branch name selects the third of the three commits that are in this repository:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

This drawing represents the idea that name `main` identifies (or "points to") commit `C`, with `C` standing in for the actual hash ID of that third commit.  Meanwhile commit `C` points to—or more precisely, stores in its metadata the hash ID of—earlier commit `B`; commit `B` points to commit `A`.  As commit `A` was the very first commit, it does not point any further back: those are all the commits in the repository.

Let's now create two new branch names, `staging` and `feature/one`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--feature/one, main, staging
```

*All three names select commit C*.  This means that the snapshot stored *in* commit `C` is what you will see regardless of *which branch name you choose*.

You can—easily—remove a file and commit.  Suppose we use:

```
git switch feature/one
```

so that the *current branch name* is `feature/one`.  We then remove `somefile` and commit.  This makes a new commit `D`, and updates the *name* `feature/one` to point to new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, staging
       \
        D   <-- feature/one (HEAD)
```

(The name `HEAD` in parentheses indicates the current branch name, in these drawings.)  If we switch back to `main` or `staging`:

```
git switch main
```

we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD), staging
       \
        D   <-- feature/one
```

Commit `D` still exists, and the name `feature/one` still points to it; the file we removed is still absent from the snapshot in `D`, and will be forever, since all commits are 100% read-only.  The file we removed before making commit `D` is, however, still here in commit `C`.  When we switched from commit `D` back to existing commit `C`, Git removed all the commit-`D` files and installed, instead, all the commit-`C` files.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>This glosses over a bunch of special cases described in [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452), but is good as a starting mental model: your working tree is where Git *extracts* the committed files, so that you can see and work on / with them.  Switching commits requires removing and replacing some of these files.  Note that a branch-change that doesn't switch *commits*, however, never requires touching *any* files.  As long as two names both select the *same commit*, you can switch back and forth without consequence.

---

> is there a simple way to remove each file names (`*.ids.json`) from my repository when merging to `staging` or `master` while keep the tracking of those file in branches that are `feature/*`?

No.  It's easy enough to do *manually*, but to automate that, you must have your merge process do it:

> This should work on pipelines ...

Git doesn't have anything called "pipelines".  Other, non-Git software that *does* have pipelines, such as Jenkins or GitHub CI, may or may not let you do what you'd do manually.  Note that each of these add-ons has something rather different, that they tend to call a "pipeline" or similar word; you've asked in a Git forum and it's impossible to guess which system you're talking about.

Comment: this is a very complete explanation thank you.  For the answer, I guess I should use something else than git to achieve this then ? The problem is, does PR conflict with the main branch just because of this files that I would ignore during the merge process. So no pipeline (I use bitbucket) run to delete those files

Comment: A bitbucket pipeline might be able to do what you want, but I haven't used Bitbucket much at all, and never used their pipeline feature myself.